# which method when display dialog show in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I opened dialog in a fragment and when come back to fragment, my fragment's view is `null Object`.
when the dialog is displaying which lifecycle method fragment is calling?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
  TextView textView;
  View view;
  FloatingActionButton actionButton;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read, container, false); 

    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtSaved);
    actionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        DialogSearch search = new DialogSearch();
        search.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"MyDialog");
      }
    });
   return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a small change,

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
        TextView textView;
        View view;
        FloatingActionButton actionButton;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read, container, false); 

            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtSaved);
            actionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

            actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DialogSearch search = new DialogSearch();
                    search.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"MyDialog");
                }
            });
    return view;   / Add this line -------   
     }
    }
```

You need to return view

when the dialog is displaying which lifecycle method fragment is calling?

```
onPause() of fragment gets called.
```

Comment: what do you show in textView ? there no code related to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149293/open-dialog-from-fragmentfragments-view-null

Comment: i put `Toast` in `onPause()` when dialog is displaying,but does not display toast

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the dialog is being showned in the `onCreateView` life cycle, that is why is the Fragment view is null. You have to do it inside the `onViewCreated` method.

```
    @Override
    public View onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //Work here, the view argument in the method is the view inflated in the onCreateView method
    });
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the problem now?